# How to establish a remote desktop connection from Windows 7 to Mac OS Leopard?

Tags: windows-7, mac, remote-desktop

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Remote desktop to Mac from various platforms (Windows, Ubuntu)](https://superuser.com/questions/117419/remote-desktop-to-mac-from-various-platforms-windows-ubuntu)

I try to make a remote desktop connection **from Win 7** machine to **Mac OS Leopard** machine. How can I accomplish that?
Thanks

**EDIT:** When I try to connect via VNC after entering the IP address and password of server, program exits with a command line is visible for 1 second and anything happens. What is the problem do you think?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you mean to control your Mac from Windows, just use VNC.

Mac has a built in VNC server. Go to System Preferences -> Sharing -> Screen sharing.

Then get a free VNC viewer for your PC, eg. http://www.realvnc.com/products/free/4.1/winvncviewer.html

Comment: When I try to connect via VNC after entering the IP address and password of server, program exits with a command line is visible for 1 second and anything happens. What is the problem do you think?

Comment: Try the UltraVNC viewer - http://www.uvnc.com/download/1082/1082viewer.html

Comment: Have tried and result is the same. Could it be related to 64 bit OS somehow? I use Win 7 Ultimate x64

Comment: That was my immediate thought, although on UVNC's site it says it's compatible. I assume you're trying from an admin account? Also try the "XP mode" if you have it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your responses. Changing connection speed from Auto to LAN solved the problem in UVNC.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Irapp](http://www.coderebel.com/products/irapp/):

> Use your Mac and PC simultaneously through a single monitor, mouse,
>   and keyboard. Welcome to the Switzerland of computing. . . iRAPP is an
>   application that gives you merged, interactive access to your Mac OS X
>   remote desktop via your PC. You can choose to view the Mac in a
>   blended session with Windows and OS operating systems into one window,
>   or you may use the built in Remote Desktop Protocol to view it in a
>   separate window. Either way, iRAPP allows you to connect from PC to
>   Mac remote desktop right within the Windows environment.

Answer (score -4):

You just need to download the following Remote Desktop connection client for your Mac and then use the Windows 7 IP address to establish a remote desktop connection from the Mac to the Windows 7 machine.

http://www.microsoft.com/mac/products/remote-desktop/default.mspx

Comment: I need the exact opposite. I need to connect mac FROM WINDOWS 7.

Comment: @EEE - Sorry, misread the question.