# remote desktop to mac

Tags: mac, remote-desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remote desktop to Mac from various platforms (Windows, Ubuntu)](https://superuser.com/questions/117419/remote-desktop-to-mac-from-various-platforms-windows-ubuntu)

What's the easiest way to remote desktop from a windows 7 machine to a mac book pro osx snow leopard?

Answer (score 1):

Mac OSX has a VNC server built into it, does it not? I would think a VNC viewer installed on your Windows 7 box would be the simplest way of going about things (and free).