# Best way to access a mac from another mac

Tags: remote-desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remote desktop to Mac from various platforms (Windows, Ubuntu)](https://superuser.com/questions/117419/remote-desktop-to-mac-from-various-platforms-windows-ubuntu)

What are some of the tools you can use to access the graphical login of a mac.

I know there is VNC, and windows has Remote Desktop Connection, but what are all of my options?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [TeamViewer](http://teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx), it allows access to a computer from anywhere (provided it is running TeamViewer as well) and can be used with different OSs, not just OS X.

Answer (score 0):

My personal solution in a Mac-only environment is the built-in Screen Sharing, plus router port forwarding and [Dynamic DNS](http://www.dyndns.com/services/dns/dyndns/) for external access when needed.

If you don't want to bother with the technical setup for external access, [MobileMe](http://www.apple.com/mobileme/) has a feature called Back To My Mac that simplifies this.

Answer (score 0):

I have several machines using the free version of [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/). You can access from another Mac, PC, iPhone (I guess a connected Touch would work), iPad or android. Encrypted, no less.

Answer (score 0):

I use iChat desktop sharing for this. There are some Apple Scripts on the internet that can be used to autoaccept connections for desktop sharing.