# How can 2 separate users share a 3rd computer in between them using their own mouse/keyboards?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, synergy

I know Synergy exists to let you share your mouse + keyboard across multiple PCs, but can multiple users use one machine in a similar fashion? Almost like running multiple instances of Synergy or allowing Synergy to connect to multiple hosts. Or maybe a different solution entirely?

We are two Windows 8.1 users trying to share a Mac. Only one user will be operating it at any time.

Comment: I edited the title slightly to remove the software rec part. If you are looking purely for software suggestions then you should delete this question and post instead on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question is a duplicate. - http://superuser.com/questions/117419/remote-desktop-to-mac-from-various-platforms-windows-ubuntu

Comment: Not really - I need 2 seperate users to seamlessly share a single mac, similar to how synergy lets you seemlessly move from using your PC to using your mac.