# Can I access this Mac system remotely?

Tags: macos

I have a MacBook and I have 6 Windows desktop systems.
I want to access the MacBook parallel same time 7 user.
Like 6 user accessing MacBook on Windows system remotely, and one user using Mac at same time.
How is it is possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a Mac Machine be used by Multiuser at same time?](http://superuser.com/questions/125636/can-a-mac-machine-be-used-by-multiuser-at-same-time) (Oh, oops, or maybe not if it's just about file sharing. In that case: [Mac OSX - How can I enable sharing with windows machines?](http://superuser.com/questions/125636/can-a-mac-machine-be-used-by-multiuser-at-same-time))

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I get your question. Do you mean that your Windows users should access the files on the MacBook? If so, it's easy: Just turn on File Sharing in System Preferences->Sharing, and make sure you activate SMB in the options dialog. Then, you can browse for the MacBook in your Network Neighborhood. There are some configuration possibilites, but those depend on what you want to do exactly.

Should you mean that your 6 users should access the GUI of Mac OS X: It's not possible, or rather, all remote and the local user would have the same screen, as Mac OS X doesn't have any Terminal Server capabilities like X11 or Windows Terminal Services.

Comment: OS X, not MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

With the Vine VNC server it is possible (with some limitations). See http://www.testplant.com/products/vine_viewer/multidesktop for details.