# OS X multiple use of same machine via VNC

Tags: macos, vnc, fast-user-switching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a Mac Machine be used by Multiuser at same time?](https://superuser.com/questions/125636/can-a-mac-machine-be-used-by-multiuser-at-same-time)

I'm wondering if I can connect to my wife's mac via VNC while she is logged in herself. I wouldn't be surprised if this isn't possible, although the machinery should be there with "fast-user-switching" support.

So, if I create a profile for myself, and after I log in (and enable the VNC server/sharing for my profile), and then my wife switches to her own account, which she uses on the physical console, Will I be able to use the mac ?

Answer (score 1):

## No.

VNC support is limited to that account. You would have to enable it on here account as well in order to be able to VNC into her machine while she is logged in.