# Fast user switching / multi user in Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, vnc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a Mac be used by multiple users at same time?](https://superuser.com/questions/125636/can-a-mac-be-used-by-multiple-users-at-same-time)

Is it possible to interact with a disconnected user session in Snow leopard (using e.g. VNC)?

I am referring to functionality similar to the administrative Remote Desktop in Windows (at least Windows 2003, I guess Vista has it too), that lets another user log into his disconnected session without interrupting the "console user".

My guess would be that the basic support for this would be there with Fast user switching, but I need some kind of server software (third party, maybe) to make it work like this. At least I couldn't find anything built-in. I tried to find a VNC server with support for this, but none of the ones a Google search provided me with had support for it...

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Can a Mac Machine be used by Multiuser at same time?](http://superuser.com/questions/125636/can-a-mac-machine-be-used-by-multiuser-at-same-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VNC does not directly interact with the user session.  It is simply forwarding the screen of the machine to the client.  RDP in Windows is an active session that interacts with the OS.  as far as I know, there isn't a way to do with with just VNC.