# From windows, how to manage a OS X machine (with different user account)

Tags: windows-7, macos, remote-desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a Mac be used by multiple users at same time?](https://superuser.com/questions/125636/can-a-mac-be-used-by-multiple-users-at-same-time)

I need to manage a Mac Pro workstation from Windows.

In wWndows is possible to use Remote Desktop with a separate account, so 2 or more users can be active at the same time.

Using VNS, is more for tech support, but I don't know if is possible for 2+ users enter the same machine as happened with Windows.

So, is this possible? How?

Answer (score 0):

RealVNC can do that, but it is $50 for a license.

Starting in OS X.4, the OS comes with a built in VNC server. I don't know how successful you will be in having another OS connect using this, but its possible you may be able to connect using the TightVNC viewer on a windows machine (it may take some effort and tweaking). You may also be able to get the unix port of TightVNC running in OS X, but again, that might take some effort and tweaking.