# Is there a tool that will allow concurrent remote sessions into an iMac?

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a Mac be used by multiple users at same time?](https://superuser.com/questions/125636/can-a-mac-be-used-by-multiple-users-at-same-time)

Hey all,

Looking for 2+ users to be able to remote into an iMac we have and each have their own session. Machine is going to be used as a platform to develop for iOS as well as a general purpose machine.

I understand that VNC is built into the OS but it doesnt appear to allow multiple sessions.  Its also fairly slow.

Is there a way I can accomplish this server type setup with my iMac?

Thanks,

Comment: Multiple monitors with multiples sections is barely even on Linux yet, and with Apple and all its cutting edge stability, I doubt it will make it on before they slay the Mac for iOS in 2012 when the world ends. Unless you mean multiple virtual monitors under one account...

Comment: What? Multiple monitors with multiple 'sections'? What does this have to do with the question? One of the strangest responses I have seen on here.

Comment: Dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/125636/can-a-mac-machine-be-used-by-multiuser-at-same-time

Answer (score 1):

From here: [Can a Mac be used by multiple users at same time?](https://superuser.com/questions/125636/can-a-mac-machine-be-used-by-multiuser-at-same-time)

If this answers your question, consider deleting it as it is a duplicate.

---

Yes, it is possible using Vine Server (OSXvnc). I never used it, but the creators claim:

> [..] in Tiger (Mac OS 10.4) all those
>   desktops can be accessed
>   simultaneously using Vine Server
>   (OSXvnc). This allows multiple users
>   to be logged in, each using his or her
>   own desktop on the same Mac.
>
> [..]
>
> All they need is a computer or PDA
>   running a VNC viewer to access Vine
>   Server (OSXvnc). Now you have a use
>   for all those old PC's!

However:

> Each user MUST be logged in using Fast User Switching. If you reboot the computer you will need to go and log-in each user with Fast User Switching to enable access via VNC.

And using the very same software simultaneously might yield problems (like when temporary files are not stored in a user area), or might break the license agreements.

I don't know if this still works in Leopard and Snow Leopard. (But a recent post on Server Fault might indicate it's tested on a recent version of OS X, hence Snow Leopard?)

Answer (score 0):

You can all remote into an iMac via ssh (System Preferences..., Sharing, Remote Login) but for a GUI it's one session at a time (System Preferences..., Sharing, Remote Management).

Comment: I know it is - I've stated that in the question and am looking for a concurrent solution.