# Can a Mac Mini Server and XCode be used for multiple students?

Tags: macos, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a Mac be used by multiple users at same time?](https://superuser.com/questions/125636/can-a-mac-be-used-by-multiple-users-at-same-time)

I'm not an administrator but Ive been given the task of finding out whether this is possible.

The scenario is like this:
At our university we are offering a course in basic iPhone programming for between 4 to 8 groups of students. We have a few iPads, iPods and iPhones but only two Mac Minis.
We want to enable the students to work on XCode in the lab (and from home if possible) without buying 8 Mac Minis.

Is this possible to do using a Mac Mini Server? If so how would it work if 2 or more groups want to use XCode simultaneously and to debug their programs on devices simultaneously?

Comment: Ask again in two months when there's multi user VNC on Mac OS X Lion.

Comment: @Daniel - Does that mean its currently not possible in any way whatsoever?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, one Mac — one active GUI user, both remote and local. There's no such thing as Windows Remote Desktop with concurrent users yet; but it's [one of the features of OS X Lion](http://www.apple.com/macosx/whats-new/features.html#screensharing). Then it *might* be possible; depending on whether multiple instances of the dev tools can run concurrently, but you can experiment here with fast user switching on a single Mac to find out whether that works.

Answer (score 0):

I enabled Fast User Switching together with the script [here](http://www.coderebel.com/2010/08/31/iphone_simulator) and it allows me to open one simulator for each user which is exactly what I needed. Also, opening more than one XCode instance, even for the same user, is perfectly okay.

However this still doesn't allow multiple users to access the computer. I have heard though that using [Vine Server](http://www.testplant.com/products/vine_viewer/multidesktop) permits it.