# Let macOS provide multiple user logon via remote simultaneously

Tags: macos, mac, virtual-machine, remote-desktop

I studied this [page](https://setapp.com/how-to/how-to-access-your-mac-remotely) on how to access the Mac remotely so the next question is how do I provide access to multiple users, everyone with their own credentials can access this remotely.

Everyone gets to work on this mac simultaneously in their own workspace, documents, desktop etc., is there a solution?

Comment: Great that you've studied that resource. What do you find if you study resources related to multiple users accessing the mac simultaneously

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a Mac be used by multiple users at same time?](https://superuser.com/questions/125636/can-a-mac-be-used-by-multiple-users-at-same-time)

Comment: See also - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/256337/does-macos-sierra-support-multiple-users-simultaneously-connecting-to-the-same-m

Comment: Thanks guys for the input