# Snow Leopard - per user VNC sessions?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, vnc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a multi-user Remote Desktop app for Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/30173/is-there-a-multi-user-remote-desktop-app-for-mac-os-x)

Can I start a new VNC session from SSH, like with Linux VNC servers such as TightVNC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking for a way to have two separate GUI login sessions active to the same Mac at the same time? As in two separate user accounts logged in running separate sets of GUI apps (as opposed to viewing/co-controlling the same login session)?

Then the answer is "No".

The WindowServer and LoginWindow processes in Mac OS X do not support having multiple separate GUI logins in full active use simultaneously. Fast User Switching allows you to suspend one user's GUI session while another user creates and runs their own GUI session, but they can't both be interacted with at the same time.

These are fundamental limitations of the GUI/windowing infrastructure of Mac OS X, and I doubt anyone will ever put in the effort to get around it.