# Controlling a Mac from a windows PC

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop, osx-lion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remote desktop to Mac from various platforms (Windows, Ubuntu)](https://superuser.com/questions/117419/remote-desktop-to-mac-from-various-platforms-windows-ubuntu)

So I have a Mac on a mostly windows network (Windows XP, at that). I'd like to be able to remote desktop into it like we do Windows PC to Windows PC on the network so different people could use it without physically passing the computer around. Does anyone have a suggested Windows Remote Desktop client for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Teamviewer](http://teamviewer.com).  You could also use  [Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection Client for Mac](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=cd9ec77e-5b07-4332-849f-046611458871&displaylang=en)

Comment: [This](http://superuser.com/questions/30173/is-there-a-multi-user-remote-desktop-app-for-mac-os-x) may interest you

Answer (score 0):

OS X.4 and up has it's own [built in VNC server](http://www.dssw.co.uk/blog/2007/05/14/a-vnc-server-is-included-in-mac-os-x-104/). You can then use [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/), [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/), [RealVNC](http://www.realvnc.com/) or any other VNC viewer on your windows machines to connect.